# C# connect Winforms to online host (goDaddy)

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, web-services

I was trying to connect my Win forms app to my online host on GoDaddy, however every time I try to connect I get access denied. I've read online that usually these hosts will block typical incoming connections.

My solution was to upload JSON responses on the host, call the specific page from the app and Deserialize the response to something that I can use. But this will take a lot of time and effort.

Do you have any other solution from which i can connected my c# winform app to my online hosted database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From GoDaddy's help:

"Applications that connect remotely to databases use similar settings. You can find database's specific information using Viewing Your Database Details with Shared Hosting Accounts.

Host Name or Server:    Your database's host name

Port
  MySQL: 3306
  MS SQL: 1433

Username    The database user's username

Password    The database user's password

Database    The name of the database

1 Free Web Hosting accounts cannot enable Direct Database Access. To upgrade your hosting account, see Upgrading or Downgrading Your Hosting Account."

https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978

So it sounds like you can enable this with your host if you are not using the 1 Free Web Hosting tier.